# Select2 not filtered when search text is entered

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have upgraded select2 into version 4. When I open select2 and enter the search text, the list filters based on what I type.

Here is the HTML

```
<select style="width: 100%;" id="fruit" multiple required>
     <option value="1">Apple</option>
     <option value="2">Pear</option>
     <option value="3">Watermelon</option>
     <option value="4">Melon</option>
     <option value="5">Pineapple</option>
     <option value="6">Orange</option>
     <option value="7">Kiwi</option>
     <option value="8">Banana</option>
     <option value="9">Papaya</option>
     <option value="10">Tangerine</option>
 </select>
```

This is for JS

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
    function matchCustom(params, data) {
        if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
          return data;
        }
        if (typeof data.text === 'undefined') {
          return null;
        }
        var terms = params.term.split(" ");
        for (var i=0; i < terms.length; i++){
            if (data.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(terms[i].toLowerCase()) === -1) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
    $('select').select2({
        matcher: matchCustom,
        closeOnSelect: false,
        multiple: true
    });
    var last_search = '';
    $('select').on('select2:open', function () {
        if (last_search != "") {
            $('#fruit').select2('search', last_search);
            $('.select2-search__field').val(last_search);
        }
    });
    $(document).on('keyup', '.select2-search__field', function () {
        var text = $('.select2-search__field').val();
        last_search = text;
    });
});
```

Initial display

[image: initial display]

When I type, this is the design

[image: search]

After I selected what I want, the list is still open and the search text is not disappear. It's not a problem. However, when I click on another place (which caused my select2 list to disappear) and click again at the select2 field, this is what happened.

[image: image1]

The last search value is "ap". The list only included the value that have "ap" in the words. But, the Searching text is exist. The "ap" value doesn't appear in the search text as expected. This code `$('.select2-search__field').val(last_search);` doesn't work as expected.

I also try to remove this code `$('#fruit').select2('search', last_search);` that is located inside the select2 open event. I got another problem when I opened select2 field for the second time.

[image: image2]

The "ap" value is the last search before I close the select2 list. When I reopened, the "ap" value shows up in the search text which is correct. But, the list is not filtered according to what I search.

The outcome that I want after I reopened select2 field is the search value appears **and** the list only filters what I search. I have been searching for this for hours. Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: Pay attention to docs: https://select2.org/searching#multi-select. They say: "For multi-select boxes, there is no distinct search control. So, to disable search for multi-select boxes, you will need to set the disabled property to true whenever the dropdown is opened or closed"

Comment: i don't want to disable search box. it is needed for easy filtering.

Comment: but it does not work properly with multi select...

Comment: then, if the list is, for example, more than 100, the user will have to scroll to the bottom if the desired value is in the bottom list.